How do I know if this battery is dead?
my Mom told me that her bluetooth speaker (Ultimate Ears Megaboom) doesn't work anymore. I'm a little experienced in electronics so I wanted to try and repair it. My assumption was, that the battery is dead. But this battery has multiple pins and I am not sure how I can check the voltage because I can't seem to figure out where + and where - is. I tried measuring the voltage across these pins but i always get 0 Volts.

Am I missing something important here or is the battery really just dead?

Well you don't know easily. Depending on what you mean by dead. It may be so discharged that the protection circuitry on the pack (it hopefully has one) has disconnected the battery cells from the load to prevent further discharge and damage. It may be deactivated by protection circuit until it is charged or it may be deactivated forever. Unless you of course reactivate it manually if possible. We can't really tell how would you know it's dead, as there are multiple ways may just appear dead while it isn't.

Easy. Use another battery, see if it fixed your problem

Most likely dead or tripped BMS. If the latter, it may be possible to charge the cells after the BMS, but would require you to make physical access to it. Personally, I use a lab supply to force charge all battery packs (individual cells if needed) to avoid the expense of a new one, but if you don’t feel certain, don’t.

There are ten holes.

Put a probe in hole 1, then the other in 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
Put a probe in hole 2, then the other in 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
Put a probe in hole 3, then the other in 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
...

Hmm... do you see a pattern here?
Polarity doesn't matter with a DVM that can read positive or negative.
After checking all, if there is not at least 5 VDC between some pair, then the battery is likely too depleted to recharge.
